# Retornar nome de Arquivo em VBS

Tags: windows, visual-basic-6, vbs

É possível retornar o nome de um arquivo/programa por um script VBS? Tipo ao arrasta e dropar no script ou em abrir com... o script, ele retorna o nome.

Comment: Jefter, creio que o que deseja é `Wscript.Arguments`.

Comment: poderia me recomendar algum material sobre?

Comment: Não é uma linguagem que domino, mas estou fazendo um exemplo e já te mando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `Wscript.Arguments` reconhece o arquivo na sequencia dos parâmetros como se fosse um executável normal e com `GetFileName` você pode pegar o nome e `GetAbsolutePathName` pegará o caminho completo.

Um exemplo de script:

```
Dim Arg

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Verifica se selecionou arrastou ao menos um arquivo
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then

    'Itera todos arquivos que soltou em uma ação
    For Each Arg in Wscript.Arguments

        'Remove possíveis espaços
        Arg = Trim(Arg)

        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(Arg)

        'Exibe um dialogo somente para testes
        MsgBox("Nome: " & objFSO.GetFileName(objFile) & " - caminho: " & objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile))
    Next
End If
```

Exemplo funcionando do script:

[image: exemplo]

---

Se deseja limitar somente para um arquivo, então mude a linha:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
```

Para

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
Dim Arg

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Verifica se selecionou arrastou um arquivo
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then

    'Itera todos arquivos que soltou em uma ação
    For Each Arg in Wscript.Arguments

        'Remove possíveis espaços
        Arg = Trim(Arg)

        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(Arg)

        'Exibe um dialogo somente para testes
        MsgBox("Nome: " & objFSO.GetFileName(objFile) & " - caminho: " & objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile))
    Next
End If
```

Para checar se é um arquivo e não uma pasta, use `FileExists`/`FolderExists`

---

Um exemplo que verifica se é arquivo e quantos selecionou:

```
Dim Arg

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Verifica se selecionou arrastou ao menos um arquivo
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then

    'Itera todos arquivos que soltou em uma ação
    For Each Arg in Wscript.Arguments

        'Remove possíveis espaços
        Arg = Trim(Arg)

        If objFSO.FileExists(Arg) Then
            Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(Arg)

            'Exibe um dialogo somente para testes
            MsgBox("Nome: " & objFSO.GetFileName(objFile) & " - caminho: " & objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile))
        Else
            MsgBox("Este arquivo não existe ou é uma pasta")
        End If

    Next
ElseIf WScript.Arguments.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox("Você mais de um arquivo")
Else
    MsgBox("Você não selecionou nenhum arquivo")
End If
```

> **Nota:** Salve o arquivo .vbs como ANSI (windows-1252 ou iso-8859-1 ou compatível), UTF-8 ou outro tipo de unicode pode não ser exibido em `MsgBox` (a não ser que faça ajustes no script)

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível. Veja o [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/PT-BR/library/office/gg278516.aspx):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Scripts\Test.txt")

Wscript.Echo "File name: " & objFSO.GetFileName(objFile)
```

Comment: penso que você não me entendeu, veja bem, este script retorna o nome do arquivo especificado pela variável objFile, minha duvida é se é possível retornar o nome do arquivo que foi aberto arrastado e soltado no script entendeu?

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer. A resposta que dei é para exatamente a sua pergunta. Arrastado e soltado? Em que parte da sua aplicação há um `Drag n drop`?

Comment: bom como posso dizer, eu consigo isso em batch, mas queria em vbs veja o seguinte
`set Replay_Locale=%1`
`echo %Replay_Locale%`
se eu fizer um drag e drop no batch ele me retorna o nome/caminho do arquivo entendeu?

Comment: Marcelo, ele quer interação Desktop com dragdrop.